# How to open file with fopen() in UWP c++?

Tags: c++, file, uwp

How can I open a file in UWP application?
My application will have additional files (e.g. Text file)
I want my program to be able to access this file. So how can I do it?

Comment: Why `flopen()`?? Please read [Create, write, and read a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files). If the samples on MSDN are not in C++ you have to select the language at the top right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make sure that the file that you are trying to open is placed in Application local folder(Folder name "LocalState")
Use the below code to find the local folder path.

```
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Streams;

textBlock1->Text = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path;
```

This will display local folder path in text block name textBlock1.

 2.) To open the file name "Sample.txt"

```
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Streams;

String^ localfolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path;
std::wstring basePath(localfolder->Data());
std::wstring fileName(L"\\Sample.txt");
basePath = basePath + fileName;
const wchar_t* fullpath = basePath.c_str();
size_t size = wcslen(fullpath) * 2 + 2;
char * StartPoint = new char[size];
size_t c_size;
wcstombs_s(&c_size, StartPoint, size, fullpath, size);

FILE *fp_testFile = NULL;
errno_t err;

err = fopen_s(&fp_testFile, StartPoint, "rb");
if (err == 0)
{
    OutputDebugStringW(L"opened");
}
else
{
    OutputDebugStringW(L"open failed");
}
```

The string conversion part is really confusing for me.
I also don't know how not to manually place the file in the local folder.
I tried added the file under Solution explorer -> Assets. But the file is not included to the local folder after deployed

Comment: `new[]`? `fopen()`? whats wrong with `std::string` and `std::fstream`? 1st snipped ... why not simply `textBlock1->Text = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path;`?

Comment: @Swordfish Thank you! for the fix in 1st snipped!! I'm using fopen() because I'm trying to reuse the code from the old c program without changing much of the code. This thing confusing me for weeks now.

Comment: *because I'm trying to reuse the code from the old c program without changing much of the code.* – Thats all fine for your private projects, but you should show best practices in answers, not legacy workarounds.